# When is Clark Kent's favorite story revealed?

Tags: dc, superman

In the "[Death and Return of Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman)" storyline, Doomsday kills Superman and the four other versions of Superman appear.  Two of the new Supermen tell Lois that they are the *original* Superman and support their claims by telling her some of their "memories" as Clark Kent.

However, it is later revealed that a fifth Superman was the original one.  He is able to convince Lois of his identity by referencing the story "To Kill a Mockingbird".

Apparently, this was Clark's favorite book and the only other person who knew that was Lois.  **Does anyone know the comic where Clark originally tells Lois that this is his favorite book?**

Comment: Clark looks a hell of a lot like Atticus Finch; http://cdn.emgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/120130105649-mockingbird-1-story-top.jpg

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nSxU2.png - Favourite movie, not book

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**He doesn't.** In the original Vol 2 serial ([#67 1992](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_67)), some 14 comics earlier, it's the **film** version that he's discloses that he's fond of. There's no mention of the novel.

[image]